# Не могу растянуть инпут

Tags: html5, css3

Не могу понять в чем проблема, checkbox в хроме растянутый (задал самому input ширину и высоту 28px). А в мазиле и опере он как на первом скрине маленький, префиксы автоматические вроде настроены.

Вторая проблема: не выводится плейсхолдер в textarea, хотя если написать что-нибудь и стереть, то он будет.

```
<textarea placeholder="Комментарий:" class="comment" name="Комментарий">
                            </textarea>
```

пример на https://jsfiddle.net/ew3wL3mg/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ создайте пример тут. Я думаю лишб немногие обладают даром ясновидения. И все они в данный момент заняты.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ew3wL3mg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема скрытого плейсхолдера в textarea решается удалением лишних пробелов из кода.

А размер чекбокс будет правильнее всего стилизовать при подменяя его картинкой-спрайтом - это более универсальное решение.

Либо если Вам нужно только увеличить его размер, то при помощи свойства *transform: scale(2);* его можно увеличить например в 2 раза.

Comment: Уберите префиксы от `transform` http://caniuse.com/#search=transform